# Delphi: How to detect key names w/wo Shift key held

Tags: delphi, text, keyboard, shortcut

I have a vclfix [project](https://code.google.com/p/native-look-vcl/) to make Delphi application more Windows native look and feel. One of my fix is to change particular shortcut text of menu items.

In concrete, if I assign `Ctrl++` to menu item "Zoom In", the fix will change the shortcut text to `Ctrl +`.

```
function ShortCutToTextOverride(ShortCut: TShortCut): string;
(**
 * This function replaces the following shortcuts
 *    "Ctrl++" ->  "Ctrl +"  |   "Ctrl+-" ->  "Ctrl -"
 *   "Shift++" -> "Shift +"  |  "Shift+-" -> "Shift -"
 *     "Alt++" ->   "Alt +"  |    "Alt+-" ->   "Alt -"
 *)
begin
  Result := OrigShortCutToText(ShortCut);

  case LoByte(Word(ShortCut)) of
    VK_OEM_PLUS, VK_ADD:
      Result := ReplaceStr(Result, '++', ' +');

    VK_OEM_MINUS, VK_SUBTRACT:
      Result := ReplaceStr(Result, '+-', ' -');
  end;
end;
```

Now I am facing a problem: When I assign `Ctrl++` to a menu item, it looks great. But somehow the shortcut might be changed to `Ctrl+=` automatically. Maybe some Delphi internal routines did that, as `=` and `+` share the same key in English keyboard layout.

**Here the question is how to know the opposite key name of `+`, regardless the keyboard layout?**

Comment: I'm interested - in what what do some of the VCL controls not match the Windows look at feel?  The vast majority of them *are* the native Windows controls.

Comment: @DavidM The major difference that troubles me is that a Delphi application renders tooltip in its own style. Although it is very close to native, but they are different. Here is my blog about that http://stanleyxu2005.blogspot.com/2008/01/native-hint-window-class.html. Also the menu item with images looks also different. I do not have time to patch it in a proper way yet.

Answer (score 0):

Link it to ctrl+**shift**+'+'

Shortcuts are only linked to the unshifted keys on a US standard keyboard.

Obviously if you want to capture the ctrl + '=' on a keuboard with a dedicated '=' key then you'll have to let the mainform capture all keystokes.

Use the TForm.KeyPreview:= True

Then add a OnKeyPress handler to the form.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to include my vclfix unit at the very beginning of a project, not in some concrete form implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is just an example to clear your mind:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (ssCtrl in Shift) then
    case Key of
      107: ShowMessage('Ctrl +');
      109: ShowMessage('Ctrl -');
    end;

  if (ssAlt in Shift) then
    case Key of
      107: ShowMessage('Alt +');
      109: ShowMessage('Alt -');
    end;

  if (ssShift in Shift) then
    case Key of
      107: ShowMessage('Shift +');
      109: ShowMessage('Shift -');
    end;
end;
```

Remeber to set **True** the property **KeyPreview** in your form.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to include my vclfix unit at the very beginning of a project, not in some concrete form implementation.